# Unable to parse string to the right date format

Tags: java, parsing, date-format

I have a date in string format and I want to parse it to date format "ddMMyy".

I used `SimpleDateFormat` as follows:

```
String stringDate = "050109";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
Date  date = dateFormat.parse(stringDate);
```

when I print the "date" I get in this format:

> Mon Jan 05 00:08:00 CET 2009

even further when I marshal the Java object I get in new format:

> 2009-01-05T00:08:00+01:00

anyone have an idea how to get the right format?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print the date in the format you parsed:

```
String fmtDate = dateFormat.format( date );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format a `Date` object, `parse` method is for parsing strings into `Date`s, not the other way around. As you can see your string is being parsed correctly into a `Date` object. If you want to format this date for output at some point you can use the `format` method of `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
String formattedDate=dateFormat.format(date);
```

where `date` is your `Date` object.

Comment: yes but the print is just a way to check the format into Date. but still the same problem in the Marshalled XML as i get 2009-01-05T00:08:00+01:00

Comment: I don't know how you are generating the XML, but often there will be a way to provide a Date marshaller implementation where you can format the date string any way you like before it's inserted into the XML. Specifics on this depend on what you are actually trying to do. For example the ksoap2 web services library often used for Android applications has something like this, and I'm sure others do too.